# Which settings files should I check in when the project team is using either of INtelliJ or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, settings

All!

In our project team, people use either IntelliJ or Eclipse IDE depending on what they are comfortable with. Eacf of the IDEs have their own settings files. For instance, IntelliJ uses .idea and .iml and Eclipse uses .project, .settings, .classpath! While some other stack overflow thread says it's not needed to check in any of these files from either IDEs if you are using Maven, I'm unsure why that's the case. None of the threads say why using Maven does not warrant (some of) the settings, .project, .classpath be checked in?

Can someone help me understand 2 things

1) Why don't we need these files to be checked in when using Maven?

2) If we must check in (Assuming Maven is not used), how do we ensure that either IDEs work okay when checking out from source control and what to check in to ensure cross compatibility.

Thanks!

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) These files are not needed because bothe IDEs can import maven projects using the pom.xml file. So the pom.xml file is your single source of project description for both IDEs.

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.m2e

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start

2) You see it right, it's hard to ensure cross-compatibility if you use only the native project files of the IDEs. Among many other things that's why it's encouraged to separate the build chain (Maven, Gradle, etc.) from the IDE. Also continuous integration systems can be configured more easily if a unified build tool is used so it's kind of a best practice to use one and keep it independent from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to switch to maven now, check in the Eclipse .project and .classpath files, Intellij is able to understand them.